# In a PictureBox, drawing a temporary circle on mouse down, to follow the mouse, until the mouseUp event is detected

Tags: c#, drawing, picturebox

I'm really new to drawing in C#, and I'm using Windows Forms instead of WPF, so maybe I'm doing it wrong from the get-go... you tell me... but I'd like to have a temporary marker put down on the PictureBox (on MouseDown) that will follow the mouse (erasing the previous drawings of itself, i.e. not leaving a trail), and then being drawn in the final position on the MouseUp event.

Here's some skeleton code that you guys can fill in:

```
bool mDown;
Graphics g;   // initialized to pictureBox1.CreateGraphics() on Form_Load, though
              // I am unsure how that differs from Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1)
SolidBrush sbGray, sbGreen;


private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = true;
    // store/push initial drawing
    g.FillEllipse(sbGray, e.X - 5, e.Y - 5, 10, 10);
}


private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mDown)
    {
        // restore/pop initial drawing, erasing old trail
        g.FillEllipse(sbGray, e.X - 5, e.Y - 5, 10, 10);
    }
}


private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // restore/pop initial drawing, erasing old trail
    g.FillEllipse(sbGreen, e.X - 5, e.Y - 5, 10, 10);
    mDown = false;
}
```

I suppose there are several ways to skin a cat, such as changing the mouse icon, so perhaps this is not even the best way to do it? Even so, I will probably need to know the answers to both questions -- whether there is a better way to do it, and also how to extract the graphics from a PictureBox (as this knowledge will most likely prove useful later anyways.)

(Note: Although the gray circles should erase themselves, the green circles should be persistent and multiple green circles should be capable of existing in the PictureBox at the same time.)

Comment: There are *many* problems with using CreateGraphics(), you haven't seen them all.  Sure, use the pictureBox1.Cursor property instead, that's what it is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the [PictureBox's Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) Event also, it is better to do all of your graphics in the Paint event since you do not have to worry about disposing the Graphic Object.. See if this is what you were wanting.

**Edit:** added code to retain points and also to clear them.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool mDown;
    SolidBrush sbGray = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
    SolidBrush sbGreen = new SolidBrush(Color.LimeGreen);
    SolidBrush sbTemp;
    Point mPosition = new Point();

    public List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Temp\Test.jpg");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mDown = true;
            mPosition = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            sbTemp = sbGray;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            points.Clear();
            sbTemp = null;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }


    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mDown)
        {
            mPosition = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            sbTemp = sbGray;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mPosition = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            points.Add(mPosition);
            sbTemp = sbGreen;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            mDown = false;
        }

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sbTemp != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(sbTemp, mPosition.X -5, mPosition.Y -5, 10, 10);
        }
        if (points != null)
        {
            foreach (var loc in points)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(sbGreen, loc.X - 5, loc.Y - 5, 10, 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello... this works great, but unfortunately the old dots from previous MouseUp's do not stick around. This sort of throws the baby out with the bathwater. I want to keep the old Circles while erasing the trail. The original idea that I had was basically explained in the OP (except for the persistence of the "Green" circles), but perhaps another approach would be to clear the graph and redraw all of the circles from scratch? I wonder which is faster... =/

Comment: @TimFoolery Just store your points in a List<Point> then you can redraw them each time that the PictureBox is invalidated.  See my edit.